# jquery validation plugin dynamic rules

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the jQuery Validation plugin and I would like to specify dynamically the rules of form:

```
<input type="text" name="MyText" id="MyText" />
var Rule="Mytext";
$('#someForm').validate({
    rules: {
        Rule: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        Rule: {
            required: 'Please fill the MyText field'
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var Rule = "Mytext";

var validation = {rules: {}, messages: {}};

validation.rules[Rule] = {
    required: true
};

validation.messages[Rule] = {
    required: 'Please fill the MyText field'
};

$('form').validate(validation);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/hGxWd/).

Comment: Is there anyway that I can pull the rules out of a file of some kind and put them in that Validation.Rules[Rule]

Comment: @DmainEvent If you have the right to access the file via XHR, then yes, you can.

Comment: @alex... Hate to be a complete noob here, but what is XHR... Also I posted a question on stackOverFlow that ask's a question along this line.  If you could comment on that and let me know if my strategy is worth its weight.  I would really appreciate it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726006/custom-rules-derived-dynamically-in-jquery
P.S I am a complete noob with JavaScript and Jquery Validation in addition to DOM and other client side programming concepts...