# jQuery validation plugin and dynamic inputs

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a section of form that dynamically generates and increments it's ids.
Something like:

```
<input type='text' name='fname1' id='fname1'/>
<input type='text' name='lname1' id='lname1'/>
```

I'm trying to go through and validate the form for the first time (I've never used the jQuery validation plugin before) and I began it with the form id "confirm"

```
$('#confirm').validate({
     rules:{
          oneoftheinputnameshere:{
             required: true
             }
            }
 });
```

The above is fine while I validate the input fields that don't change, but how would I go about selecting something to validate when I don't know how many times it'll be generated? I looked at some other questions about this and adding a class to every input field that is required, but I'm not sure if that's right or how to go about implenting it.

Any help would be great

EDIT: the ids would increment by one so 'fname2', 'fname3', etc

Comment: Have a look at this post, it should help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440724/jquery-validation-plugin-dynamic-rules?rq=1

Comment: Thanks - I had seen this but was having trouble applying it to my project. It was def the right direction though.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a fair amount of HTML code is missing from your post, but what you’re looking for is either jQuery [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) or [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) depending on how you want to approach it.

[`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) would be good for dynamically generating (and storing the names of) the ids based on another element like an array, and [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) would be good for iterating through elements of the table using something like jQuery [`.contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/) (yes they can stack).  I know it’s all a bit confusing so take some time to read up on the above jQuery methods.

Comment: I only gave sections of code (admittedly, probably not the parts that could help others understand my question more clearly). JanR pointed me in the right direction. Had to add the validation rules as the new ids were being created.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below link for Dynamic validation example

http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/dynamic-totals.html

Example:Markup

```
<textarea style="display:none" id="template">
    <div class="row" >
        <input name="form{0}" id="form{0}" title="Please enter your username" required >    
    </div>
</textarea>

<form id="orderform"  method="get" action="foo.html">
    <div id="orderitems">   
    </div>
     <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<button id="add">Add another input to the form</button>
```

Script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
// only for demo purposes
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        submitHandler: function() {
            alert("submitted!");
        }
    });
    $().ready(function() {
        $("#orderform").validate({
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                error.appendTo( element.parent(".row"));
            }
        });

        var template = jQuery.validator.format($.trim($("#template").val()));

        function addRow() {
            $(template(i++)).appendTo("#orderitems");
        }

        var i = 1;
        // start with one row
        addRow();
        // add more rows on click
        $("#add").click(addRow);
    })
     </script>
```

Comment: Answers should be fully self-contained and not rely solely on the health of an external link.  Please show the relevant code within your answer _along with_ the link.